# How change Safari's system background (theme-color)?

Tags: html, css

Safari uses "theme-color" to tint its navigation bar at the top.

BBC News uses red color, so the whole browser is red (https://www.bbc.com/news

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DEbC7.png)

Problem is, if you drag page away from right side or bottom, there is also red color under it.

1. Is there a way to set "system" (under page) background, besides "theme-color"? Let's say, I want for navigation bar to be red, but background from right to be white.
2. If going into weird hacking and using negative margins on html/body to stretch content beyond bounds, is there a stable way to compensate scrolling bounds without breaking the whole layout?